# Мне надо отсортировать экземпляры объекта по голу

Tags: python

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, position, number, goals):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.number = number
        self.goals = int(goals)

    def toString(self):
        return 'Name: {}\nPosition: {}\nNumber: {}\nGoals: {}'.format(self.name, self.position, self.number, self.goals)

p1 = Player('Salah', 'ATC', 11, 152)
p2 = Player('Ronaldinho', 'FRW', 10, 256)
p3 = Player('Pele', 'ATC', 7, 4525)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [122]: [p.toString() for p in sorted([p1, p2, p3], key=lambda x: x.goals)]
Out[122]:
['Name: Salah\nPosition: ATC\nNumber: 11\nGoals: 152',
 'Name: Ronaldinho\nPosition: FRW\nNumber: 10\nGoals: 256',
 'Name: Pele\nPosition: ATC\nNumber: 7\nGoals: 4525']
```

---

```
In [123]: [p.toString() for p in sorted([p1, p2, p3], key=lambda x: x.goals, reverse=True)]
Out[123]:
['Name: Pele\nPosition: ATC\nNumber: 7\nGoals: 4525',
 'Name: Ronaldinho\nPosition: FRW\nNumber: 10\nGoals: 256',
 'Name: Salah\nPosition: ATC\nNumber: 11\nGoals: 152']
```